# Need a valid certificate for AWS Windows EC2 instance. Does Amazon Certificate manager provide certificates for EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, qualys

I am running a Qualys scan on a Windows EC2 instance and it reports some vulnerabilities. One of them is "SSL Certificate - Subject Common Name Does Not Match Server FQDN".

Solution for this, as recommended by Qualys, is to "Please install a server certificate whose Subject commonName or subjectAltName matches the server FQDN."

Now the problem is the self-signed certificates which are not verified by a third party.
How do i get a valid certificate for this scenario such that Qualys does not report the error.
I looked into ACM, but i guess it does not provide certificates for EC2.

Can anyone provide an insight on how to go about this?
Where do i get a valid certificate and how to add it to the instance.
I am using Cloudformation template to create the instacne using a Custom AMI created using packer. I mention this because it would be helpful to know if the steps to add certificate need to be added to the AMI creation stage.

Comment: *"Now the problem is that AWS provides self-signed certificates which are not verified by a third party."*  No... I don't believe it's "AWS" that provides such a cert.  Unfortunately, you're inadvertently omitting some potentially useful detail from your question.  If your server does not have a valid cert, why is it even exposed to the Internet?  What is the Subject CN/AN of the cert in question?

Comment: I have launched an AWS EC2 Windows instance. While trying to RDP into the machine, it throws following error:
"The Certificate could not be verified back to a root certificate."
The certificate name is the hostname of the instance.
Also this certificate does not have a Subject CN/AN.
I have not provided any certificate here, so I am assuming it's a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately You can not use Certificate issued by [AWS Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) directly on EC2 Directly.

You can use it On Load Balancer and Cloudfront and API Gateways , [Refer this](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/getting-started/).

But a Workaround is that if you have single EC2 Put it behind Classic LB And terminate ssl to LB so that when you try to access your content on ec2 it is via HTTPS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass a scan like this is restrict access to your instance so your only exposing public services (like HTTP or HTTPS), and then "harden" the configuration of each required public service. All none public services/ports should be limited to just your IP address(/es).  That will probably fix a number of your issues reported by the scan.

RDP and numerous other services (MSSQL, MSDeploy, POSH Remoting to name a few) are for administrators only and should not be visible to a Qualys scan (or hackers and bots that roam the internet...).

As Kush suggests above, adding a load balancer would allow you to use ACM certificates for web traffic, but it also adds an additional layer of security between the internet and your instance. This means you can further limit access to your instance to just your VPC - as public web traffic would go via the load balencer in your VPC, not directly to your instance anymore.

If your hosting a website over HTTPS without a load balancer you will also need to edit the SChannel settings (component responsible for SSL/TLS in Windows) to pass the scan as well as installing a valid certificate for the website.

You can edit SChannel by hand in the registry here: 
`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\`

(Reboot required - take a snapshot before you start ;)

**WARNING** - misconfiguring SChannel can break RPD or limit which web browsers can access your site etc. Test carefully!

FYI I find it easier to use a tool called IIS Crypto to configure SChannel (https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto) - it has a GUI and a CLI interface for scripting changes to SChannel. (You can still break your server with this tool though!)

If you want to look at using ACM and a loadbalencer with CloudFormation i would suggest registering & approving the certificate via the aws console and make a note of the ARN of the certificate. This ARN can be used when creating a loadbalencer in a CloudFormation template.

NOTE: The above will resolve the issue on your scan, but not actually fix it. It is possible to use your own certificate for RDP (never tried), but not an ACM cert sadly. You could also look at a service like LetsEncrypt to get a free/basic certificate. Another option to avoid this error is you could export the self-signed cert from the instance and import it into your computer ( or domain?)'s certificate store.